# How to get Places to visit using google apis or google play services in android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-play-services

I want to create a travel app for users for free.
I want user to get the nearby **

> places to visit

** like we get by search in google below.
[image]

How to do that I am new to android programming.
Please share if any tutorial is available to that.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all you will need to use **Google Maps Android API v2**. For the first time it could be complicated, but I think one of the best tutorials is here [Google Maps Android API v2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) .
   This allows you to use Google Maps in your application.
2. In order to get nearest places there is also API, you should look for **Google Places**. One of tutorials is here [Google Places](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/)

If you new to android programming I recommend you to learn android basics, because Google Maps are placed in fragments - which can be quite complicated for the first time. Also remember that official guide is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning google places. Exactly what i am looking for but couldn't remember the name.